# Trying to do the series "1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5..." in python, anyone got any ideas?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script to compute the following series:

1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4...

I would be grateful if anyone could offer some guidance on how to make this work for any n value?

So far I have only been able to do this by hardcoding all the operations :D

Thanks in advance!

my current solution:

```
def seriesrun(x,n):
    ncurrent = 0
    total = 1
    while ncurrent <= n:
        if ncurrent == 0:
            ncurrent = ncurrent + 1
            total = total * 1
            print(ncurrent, total)
        elif ncurrent == 1:
            ncurrent = ncurrent + 1
            total = total - x
            print(ncurrent, total)
        elif ncurrent == 2:
            ncurrent = ncurrent + 1
            total = total + x**2
            print(ncurrent, total)
        elif ncurrent == 3:
            ncurrent = ncurrent + 1
            total = total - x**3
            print(ncurrent, total)
        elif ncurrent == 4:
            ncurrent = ncurrent + 1
            total = total + x**4
            print(ncurrent, total)
        elif ncurrent == 5:
            ncurrent = ncurrent + 1
            total = total - x**5
            print(ncurrent, total)
    return total

x = int(input('What is your starting x value?\n'))
n = 5
# n = int(input('How far should the series go?'))
# the current n position you are at...

print('Final answer is: '+str(seriesrun(x,n)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for explicit exponentiation. Each term is `-x` times the previous term.

```
def seriesrun(x, n):
    result = 0
    term = 1

    for _ in range(n):
        result += term
        term *= -x  # -x == 1 * -x, x^2 == (-x) * (-x), -x^3 == x^2 * (-x), etc
    return result
```

Comment: Saves the redundant cost of an exponentiation, very optimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
series = 0
pow = 0
while True:
    series += (-1*x)**pow
    pow += 1
```

This is an infinite loop, so it's up to you to add an exit condition.

Edit: forgot alternating sign

Answer (score 2):

Well, addition and subtraction are alternating according to some law:

```
result = sum((-1)**i * x**i for i in range(5))
```

That `(-1)**i` will be either one or negative one:

```
>>> [(-1)**i for i in range(5)]
[1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
```

Comment: Or just `(-x)**i`

Comment: Ooh that’s a good point! I remember that from maths class  that (-1)^2 is 1 and (-1)^1 is -1 thanks so much I think I can do it from there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def seriesrun(x, n):
    power = 0
    s = 0

    while power < n:
        s += (-x)**power

        power +=1
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the underlying rule/structure of the series:

```
result = 1
for i in n:
    result += (-x)**i
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

```
from functools import reduce


def seriesrun(x, n):

    return reduce(lambda c, i: c + x**i*(-1)**i , range(n + 1), 0)
```